A Calculation of Limiting Distribution by Fourier Transform

I am studying asymptotic formula for the periodic orbit in suspension of shift of finite type. The attached picture shows a part that I don't quite understand
Here $\lambda(\tau)$ is the quantity whose distribution we are interested in. It takes value in $\mathbb{R}^{+}$.
My question is that how can we use the asymptotic formula
$ \frac {\sum_{x<\lambda(\tau)\le x+1} e^{2\pi ik\lambda(\tau)}}{\sum_{x<\lambda(\tau)\le x+1} 1} \sim e^{2\pi i k x}\frac{h}{h+2\pi ik}$
to obtain that the limiting distribution of $\{\lambda(\tau): x<\lambda(\tau)\le x+1 \}$ as $x\to \infty$ is $\frac{he^{hy}}{e^{h}-1}$.
The author did this by noticing that $e^{2\pi ikx} \frac{h}{h+2\pi i k}$ is the Fourier transform of the probabilit density $\frac{he^{hy}}{e^{h}-1}$ tanslated through an angle $2\pi x$. But I can't see how the manipulation goes through. Could someone explain to me in more details?
